# wordpress custom search for post under selected category

Tags: php, wordpress, search, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I want to create a custom post search under a particular category. How can I create that.

How to create a custom where condition related to that particular category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try hijacking the search results (in search.php) if you have a certain query.

Meaning:

if a category (ID) is sent (perhaps as `catID`) by the search form together with the usual `s` variable, do a new `query_posts('s=$s&paged...&cat=$catID');`.

else just let the internal search take care of the results.